# c# : How To use a Text File Which added to My project From 'add new items\general'

Tags: c#, resources

Hi I am recently using Visual Studio 2008. My problem is I already added a text file into my project [''add new items\general\Text File''].[Is not it a embedded data like icon file or background image file ?] I want to store some data into it. But dont know how to open this file. Please any opinion will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read embedded resource text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either place the file at some place (eg relative to .EXE) that you can reconstruct at runtime and open it.

Another approach is to add it to your resources.

If you want to read and write it, you'll have to pick another place, like `Application.UserAppDataPath`.

---

In the Menu, select Project|Properties|Resources.
On the resources page, select "Add existing File" and pick your textfile. It will get a simplified name (like TextFile1) that is a valid C# identifier.

In your code, you can get the *contents* with

```
 string s = Properties.Resources.TextFile1;
```

Comment: No thats not my problem. I know how to handle file system. But my problem is I want to use embedded data which is already embedded into my project dll or exe [like icon and in that case text file].

Comment: OK, that would be the resources option.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think it will be all.